# How to merge Lists in Python?Merging python lists (0,1,2) & (A,B,C) to get (0A, 1B, 2C)

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have two lists that I need to merge, but the normal merging questions that I saw didn't seem to help.

```
l1 = (0,1,2,3)
l2 = ('A','B','C','D')
```

And I need it to become

```
((0,'A'), (2,'B'), (3,'C'))
```

Comment: What kind of pattern are you going at?

Comment: None of the answers match your required output. It would help if you explained how you expect to get from A to B. Also those are `tuple`s, not `list`s. A good intro is http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html. Good luck!

Comment: The answers are placeholders, we are racing :) Should be better now that the question is 7 minutes old. The question seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: @DanRoss Look what he expects as output.  I thought it was a simple `zip` too, but I'm afraid not.

Comment: Oh, right. My eyes added the double quotes so my brain wouldn't see the problem. I'm sure he wants a sequence of strings, and doesn't care if they are in a list or tuple.

Comment: "I want: (01,2B,3C)", yet you accept an answer that yields "['0A', '1B', '2C', '3D']", which is entirely different. I'm very confused.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: `(01,2B,3C)` is not valid Python, so it was one of those "who's closest" questions. Let's hope the poster tries to be more specific next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> A = ('0','1','2','3')
>>> B = ('A','B','C','D')
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(A, B)]
['0A', '1B', '2C', '3D']
```

For any number of lists

```
>>> lists = (A, B)
>>> [''.join(x) for x in zip(*lists)]
['0A', '1B', '2C', '3D']
```

Comment: Pure win for covering the general case with a shorter one liner :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to result to be a list of strings:

```
[ '%s%s' % (x,y) for x,y in zip(list1, list2) ]
=> ['0A', '1B', '2C', '3D']
```

Also, if `list1` is `[0,1,2,3,...]`, you can use `enumerate` instead:

```
[ '%s%s' % (i,y) for i,y in enumerate(list2) ]
```

Comment: What is the conceptual difference between this approach and the provided by jamylak?  The answer by jamylak seems more clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]: tuple(("%s%s" % (a, b) for a, b in zip((1,2,3),('a','b','c'))))
Out[4]: ('1a', '2b', '3c')
```

A while ago, I just browsed through a bunch of the official Python docs, including [built in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). It's not as dry as your usual programming manual.